# how to append AND to my Laravel query in Controller

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-7

The following method fetches the search data, i want to add another field "month" in the query.

*for example in SQL*

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE name="search_variable" 
OR email="search_variable" 
AND month="month_variable"
```

**This is my controller**

```
public function search(Request $req){

    $search = $req->get('search');
    $month = $req->get('month');

    $sand = DB::table('sand')
                ->where('name','LIKE','%'.$search.'%')
                ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');

    return view('sand.index',['sand'=>$sand], compact('search'));
}
```

Comment: You would need brackets to make that work correctly `WHERE (... OR ...) AND...`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sub query :

```
$sand = DB::table('sand')
   ->where(function($query) use($search) {
      $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
   })
   ->where('month', $month)
   ->get();
```

Comment: One issue, it says unexpected "}" operator!

Comment: I mistake a `;`, just updated.  try again

Comment: Please mark it accepted, if it helped